# Solidity: calling a imported contract's function without inheritance, Calling a imported contract interface and passing its implemented contract add

Tags: erc-20, inheritance

This is the error I'm getting, I'm trying to implement ERC20's `_transfer` function without inheritance, calling its Interface IERC20 and passing the ERC20 deployed contracts address and then calling the `_transfer` function.

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Member "_transfer" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC20.
   --> contracts/Custom/jackpot.sol:123:9:
    |
123 |         IERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138)._transfer(msg.sender,0xd9145CCE52D386f254917 ...
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Smart contract code:

```
function insertPartcipantsInJackpot(uint256 counter) 
override
payable
external 
{   

    require(msg.value >= _jackPots[counter]._entryFee,
    "You dont have enough balance to participate in this event");
    //check balance of caller > entry fee

    IERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138)._transfer(msg.sender,0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138,_jackPots[counter]._entryFee);
    //deduct that amount

    _jackPots[counter]._prizePool += _jackPots[counter]._entryFee;
    //put that entry fee in that pool

    require(_jackPots[counter]._endTime>_dateTime._now(),
    "This Participant Cannot Enter This Jackpot, Because The Event has already started");

    _jackPots[counter]._participants.push(msg.sender);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IERC20 doesn't exist _transfer() function but exist transfer() function (wrote in this way)! For call this function you must to change this line about your smart contract code:

```
IERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138)._transfer(msg.sender,0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138,_jackPots[counter]._entryFee);
```

with:

```
IERC20(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138).transfer(msg.sender,0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138,_jackPots[counter]._entryFee);
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-transfer-address-uint256-).

Comment: Thanks a lot Kerry, Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Kerry is there a specific name for the interaction of one smart contract to another without inheritance, The one you just solved.